# JPA / Hibernate support for snowflake

Tags: hibernate, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently trying to integrate an existing application to the snowflake data warehouse.
I am using hibernate 5.0 and snowflake jdbc driver 3.x.
On application start up the data source initialization is throwing following error

```
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException: null
```

I looked at the snowflake jdbc driver and quite a few methods are not supported and throwing this error.

Has anyone tried this and was able to make this work ?

Comment: There's no JPA / Hibernate support as of now with Snowflake JDBC driver. At least not officially from Snowflake side.

Answer (score 0):

I had this integration worked out. For my JPA repositories, I extended CrudJpaRepository and used Native SQL queries to fetch the required result set. The result set can be copied over to a DTO and returned in the response back to the application front-end. Given the capability of Snowflake to cache query results, performance of the APIs aren't much hindered even with large sets of data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).